# Textbox values are not calculated right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textbox, sum

I have created a form using html and jquery. It is connected to a db and it should enter in the db the values which are written in the textboxes. But I have the following problem. If a specific textbox has no value typed, it should alert, and prevent datae from entering to db. It goes well. But as well, I want to have a textbox, and if the value of this textbox does not equal to the sum of the others, it should alert, and do the same with db. And there is the problem. It is not getting the right sum. I mean, if i have in the first textbox the value 15, and then in the others textboxes, value 10, and then, value 5.. (10+5 equals with the first textbox) it should not alert, and do what it requires to enter in the db this datae. But it doesn't. It alerts and so on. How can I get this sum right from a textbox to another? Thanks

```
function checkForm() {
    if ($('#nr_articol').val().length === 0) {
        alert("Nr articol trebuie sa fie introdus! ");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function checkForm2() {
    if ($("#scurt_smd").val() + $("#incomplete_smd").val() + $("#bile").val() + $("#scurt_val").val() + $("#incomplete_val").val() + $("#lipsa_smd").val() + $("#invers_smd").val() + $("#componente_lipsa").val() + $("#componente_inversate_1").val() + $("#lipire_hotbar").val() + $("#componente_inversate_2").val() + $("#componente_inversate_3").val() + $("#componente_inversate_4").val() != $('#optic').val() || $('#electric').val()) {
        alert("Ai introdus mai multe sau mai putine bucati decat ai verificat in total. Verifica inca odata!");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submitbtn').click(function () {
        if (checkForm() == true) {
            if (checkForm2() == true) {
                var frm = $('#form');
                // var data = JSON.stringify(frm.serializeArray());
                var data = frm.serializeArray();
                console.log(data);

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'http://localhost:3000/',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    crossDomain: true,
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function () {
                        alert('sucessfully inserted');
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }

                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You shoude use `Number` or `parseInt` to convert inputs' value to `number` before adding the input values. As their defaults should be `string`.

Answer (score 0):

What is the result of all those numbers added together? You might need to cast each of the values to an int:

```
parseInt($("#scurt_smd").val());
```

It might be doing string concatenation instead, so 1 + 2 + 3 would come up as "123" instead of 6.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yea. I get it. All those values togheter should show a sum of the values entered in those textboxes..  It's a possibility to concanate ..

Comment: It isn't working parsint to Int.. I mean, it's not doing anything no matter values are entered.

Answer (score 0):

2 issues.

1. As I commented, you should parse the inputs' value to int before sum. As input.value is string, what you do now is concating them.
2. In your `A + B + C + .... != Y || Z` equation, you might want the sum either equal to Y or Z, but the fact is, if `Z` can be evaluated to `true`, then the statement is always true, you should write:

```
var sum = A + B + C + .......;
if (sum != Y || sum != Z)
```

to match your expectation.

So you can rewrite the `checkForm2` to

```
function checkForm2() {
  // Get sum.
  var sum = parseInt($("#scurt_smd").val(), 10) + parseInt($("#incomplete_smd").val(), 10) + parseInt($("#bile").val(), 10) +
                        parseInt($("#scurt_val").val(), 10) + parseInt($("#incomplete_val").val(), 10) + parseInt($("#lipsa_smd").val(), 10) +
                        parseInt($("#componente_lipsa").val(), 10) + parseInt($("#lipire_hotbar").val(), 10) + parseInt($("#invers_smd").val(), 10) + 
                        parseInt($("#componente_inversate_1").val(), 10) + parseInt($("#componente_inversate_2").val(), 10) + parseInt($("#componente_inversate_3").val(), 10) + 
                        parseInt($("#componente_inversate_4").val(), 10);

    var optic = parseInt($('#optic').val(), 10);
    var electric = parseInt($('#electric').val(), 10);

    // You may need to check all of them are valid numbers 
    // like 
    // if (isNaN(sum) || isNaN(optic) || isNaN(electric)) {
    //   do something.
    // }

    // If sum is not equal to any of them. or if the 3 values should all be the same, replace && with ||
    if (sum !== optic && sum !== electric) {
        alert("Ai introdus mai multe sau mai putine bucati decat ai verificat in total. Verifica inca odata!");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```